# Broken hyperlinks in RTF file in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I'm using a `RichTextBox` to display an RTF file, which includes a single hyperlink. The link text is not a URL (the target *is* a valid URL). The RTF was created with Word. Both Word and WordPad properly recognize the links (WordPad does not launch the links, but shows the appropriate hand cursor).

When I load the RTF into a `RichTextBox` the links appear formatted correctly (blue and underlined), but rather than behaving like a link, when the cursor moves over the link it remains an I-beam, the `LinkClicked` event will not fire, and it actually shows the target between angle brackets after the link (this does not seem correct). Since the link text is not a URL, `DetectUrls` does not help here.

Is there a reason that `RichTextBox` does not properly handle these links, or a way to make them work as expected?

Here is the code.

```
TipView.Rtf = tips[tipIndex];
// I've also tried TipView.LoadFile, with identical result
```

To reproduce the issue, create an RTF document with Word (I'm using 2000) containing one link whose text is not a URL but targets a valid URL, and programatically load the .rtf file into a `RichTextBox` (I'm using .NET 2.0 in C# Express 2008).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To support hyperlinks, you need [`RICHEDIT50W` version of "rich edit"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls).

For that:

- Either use .NET Framework 4.7, which uses `RICHEDIT50W` natively in `RichTextBox`.
- In older versions of .NET Framework, you can modify `RichTextBox` to use `RICHEDIT50W`:

  ```
    public class ExRichText : RichTextBox
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryW",
                   CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryW(string s_File);

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var cp = base.CreateParams;
                LoadLibraryW("MsftEdit.dll");
                cp.ClassName = "RichEdit50W";
                return cp;
            }
        }
    }
  ```

---

*Based on [RichTextBox Selection Highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32591157/850848#32618479) and [RichTextBox cannot display Unicode Mathematical alphanumeric symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47433656/850848#47437868)*.

---

Once you upgrade to `RICHEDIT50W`, you might need an additional fix:
[Some hyperlinks don't trigger the LinkClicked event when loading a file into RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56936777/850848)