# Hide hyperlink URL in RichTextBox (Windows Forms)

Tags: .net, forms, hyperlink, richtextbox

Hyperlinks are displayed with both a "friendly name" and the actual link itself in RichTextBox in Windows Forms (.NET).

Example:

Google <http://www.google.com>

What I really want is:

[Google](http://www.google.com)

Anyone know how to only show the friendly name in the hyperlink, and hide the actual link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doomed man :). See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1647004/613207) and corresponding codeproject article as well.

Comment: It's not true, as my answer to the linked question shows: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1647004/850848#50391203