# Can you use EM_GETTEXTEX to the the selected RTF of a rich edit control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, frameworks, richtextbox

I"m trying to come up with a way of getting the *rich* (RTF-formatted) text of a selection within a rich edit control (WinForms *RichTextBox*) using Win32 API--a way which is guaranteed to include all hidden (invisible) rich text, regardless of the .NET platform and where the hidden text is within a selection. Can I do this using EM_GETTEXTEX message? If so, what would the code be (in VB.NET if possible, though I can convert to it--and as simply as possible)? Remember: rich text, not plain; and selection, not all. (*SelectedRtf* is reliable for .NET Framework 4.6.x, but not .NET Framework 4.7+.)

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6.x and 4.7.x use a different version of the Control (`RICHEDIT20W` vs. `RICHEDIT50W`). What is the actual problem, though? Both `.SelectedText` and `.SelectedRtf` show hidden text (`\\v - \\v0`). `EM_GETTEXTEX` returns text, not the RTF content -- If you want to use the previous version of the Control in . NET Framework 4.7.1+, for whatever reason, see [RTF to plain text with RichTextBox not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75260288/7444103)

Comment: The version of the rich edit control for .NET Framework 4.7.x (not 4.6.x) has a bug (since fixed, though I'm not sure how to download and install the fix without upgrading VS itself) which prevents hidden text from being shown for .Text and .SelectedText. I've crafted a workaround for that using non-public properties of the RichTextBox (via reflection). However, when it comes to *rich* text, .Rtf returns all hidden rich text, whereas .SelectedRtf may return all, some, or none of the hidden rich text based on where the hidden text is vis-a-vis the selection--and above hack is worthless there!

Comment: It is possible, I've discovered, to get selected rich text via Win32 APIs, although that involves callbacks for streaming ,messages. What I don't know is whether the appropriate Win32-API technique for getting selected rich text will return all hidden rich text in the selection, regardless of its location therein, the way .SelectedRtf ought to, but does only with .NET Framework 4.6.x. Another forum has given me an API-oriented equivalent of .SelectedRtf, and I will test it to see if it's more reliable. But it anyone already knows, please tell.